# How to get response iframe data by using cUrl with shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

An oscilloscope interface website which IP is 192.xxx.xx.xxx　(My computer were connected with same AP), here you can input commands and send commands to get the oscilloscope signal data immediately as the following screenshot:

[SCPI_GUI_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbKZ2.png)

I want to use `curl` in shell(Ubuntu 18.04) to get the response output data from it, and my attempt is:

`curl -X POST "http://192.xxx.xx.xxx/scpictrl.htm" --data "request=MEAS%3ARES%3AACT%3F%20RMS&cmd=Send"`

and complete curl response here [curl_response@hackmd](https://hackmd.io/pYWqRAQMShmfS6mp5DH6Qw).
Notice that HTTP status is OK, but I can't get the response data in iframe.

```
<iframe name="response" width="685" height="175" class="article">
Your browser is unable to display inline frames.</iframe></td>
```

So I used Google Chrome(Press F12) to view page source in iframe structure, here shows that:

```
<body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1029.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">6.906319E-03
</body>
```

6.906319E-03 is the response data that I want to gain.

My question is:

1. Can I get iframe data only using `curl` in shell?  If we can't get those data using shell, is there any solution for these questions?
2. Suppose we can obtain those data normally, how can we abstract these data from `curl`?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: If you are using only curl, you'll need some logic to parse the HTML. You could start by `grep`ing something like `data-gr-ext-installed` and manually parsing the result of the data, or you could do something slightly more advanced and use a regular expression and capture group.

Comment: "If we can't get those data using shell, is there any solution for these questions?" There are several. Python's `request` and `beautifulsoup` modules are good for HTTP requests and HTML parsing. Node's playwright and puppeteer modules are useful for web scraping in general. Some older technologies include Selenium. The list goes on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @h0r53, I think I will pay attention to be familiar with `grep` command.

Comment: No, no, no! Please don't parse HTML with `grep` or regular expressions! This is way too error prone, as has been explained countless times on this website already. Use an XML/HTML parser instead (after you've figured out how to tweak the curl-command to get the info you want).

Answer (score 0):

The post action should have an effect on the iframe src url. Why dont use this url directly ?

Comment: As it stands this is more of a comment than an answer